# Ansible: Fails at curl command

Tags: ansible

I wrote a small playbook which will increase with time.

First i wrote a script on Remove server which has permission to visit "https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.65/bin/" and download the tomcat source , content of script file is

```
#!/bin/bash -x
version="9.0.65"
filename="apache-tomcat-"$version".tar.gz"
cd /root/ApacheTomcat/files
curl -fk https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.65/bin/apache-tomcat-"$version".tar.gz -o $filename
if [[ -e /root/ApacheTomcat/files/$filename ]]
        then
                echo -e "\nApache Tomcat $version downloaded under $PWD on `hostname -i`"
else
        echo -e "\nProblem occured please check it"
fi
```

Then i wrote a small playbook on ansible controller and have following contents

```
---                                                         
- name: Download Latest version of Apache Tomcat            
  hosts: 172.16.8.50                                        
  tasks:                                                    
    - name: Downloading Apache on Central Repository Server 
      command: sh /root/ApacheTomcat/apachetomcat.sh        
      register: _check_download_apache_status               
    - name:                                                 
      debug:                                                
        var: _check_download_apache_status                  
...
```

if i run shell script on server it works and downloads the file, but if i run it via ansible playbook it gives this error "Could not resolve host: dlcdn.apache.org; Unknown error"

```
ansible-playbook apache-update.yaml -b

PLAY [Download Latest version of Apache Tomcat] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.16.8.50]

TASK [Downloading Apache on Central Repository Server] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.16.8.50]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.16.8.50] => {
    "_check_download_apache_status": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "sh",
            "/root/ApacheTomcat/apachetomcat.sh"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.016762",
        "end": "2022-08-15 11:35:11.229642",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2022-08-15 11:35:11.212880",
        "stderr": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- -
-:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dlcdn.apache.org; Unknown error",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current",
            "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed",
            "",
            "  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dlcdn.apache.org; Unknown error"
        ],
        "stdout": "\nProblem occured please check it",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "",
            "Problem occured please check it"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.16.8.50                : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: You are missing the point of ansible. You should not write shell scripts and execute them with ansible, you should have ansible do those steps from your script, otherwise you'll have a hard time making this idempotent. Ansible can easily download files - why do you want to use this script instead?

Comment: Yes, i understand that ansible can easily download the file but problem is , our security team will never allow ansible controller to reach internet as it has access to all the Financial Servers. Forget internet it is not even allowed to be accessible from same subnet. Only PAM solution is allowed to access. For idempotent i will use script module and pass create or remove parameter available in script module.

Comment: But i found the solution i pass proxy flag with curl "curl --proxy http://10.6.2.81:8080 -fk https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.65/bin/apache-tomcat-"$version".tar.gz -o $filename" and now it is working

Comment: Ansible has no problem downloading files on remote machines (which appears to be allowed) - downloading on the "controller" and copying is (most of the time) unneeded overhead

Comment: It looks as if you're running a `bash` script using `sh`. This is not the error, but it would cause errors on systems where `sh` is not `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding

> *I wrote a small playbook which will increase with time.*

and based on given comments, you could simply start with an example like

```yaml
---
- hosts: central_repository_server # or your remote hosts
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
  
    VERSION: "9.0.65"

  tasks:
  
  - name: Download latest version of Apache Tomcat
    get_url:
      url: "https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v{{ VERSION }}/bin/apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
    register: result
    environment:
      http_proxy: "localhost:3128"
      https_proxy: "localhost:3128"
```

---

Since I haven't provided a fully functional and tested solution before, but only an idea and a way how you could solve your problem, please find here one working example.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    VERSION: "9.0.65"

  tasks:

  - name: Get file using 'uri' module
    uri:
      url: "https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v{{ VERSION }}/bin/apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz"
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
      method: GET
      status_code: 200,304
      creates: "apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz"
    environment:
      http_proxy: "localhost:3128"
      https_proxy: "localhost:3128"
```

**Further Documentation**

It is recommend to read every module documentation and get familiar with the certain properties and different behavior.

- [`get_url` module – Downloads files from HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP to node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html)
- [`uri` module – Interacts with webservices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html)
- [`unarchive` module – Unpacks an archive after (optionally) copying it from the local machine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html)

Comment: It gives error, i think because of "creates" parameter

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (get_url) module: creates Supported parameters include: attributes, backup, checksum, client_cert, client_key, content, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, force_basic_auth, group, headers, http_agent, mode, owner, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, sha256sum, src, timeout, tmp_dest, unsafe_writes, url, url_password, url_username, use_proxy, validate_certs"}

Comment: Furthermore, i set the "environment: http_proxy: PROXY_IP:PORT" at play level. and in task i added use_proxy: yes, but it keep giving below error

Comment: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "/root/ApacheTomcat/files", "elapsed": 0, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0750", "msg": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", "owner": "root", "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0", "size": 41, "state": "directory", "uid": 0, "url": "https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.65/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.65.tar.gz"}

Comment: @OmiPenguin, right, I haven't provided a fully functional and tested solution, but an idea or a way how you could solve your problem. You may need to check module `uri` or which has the parameter `creates` or the module `unarchive`.

Comment: @OmiPenguin, I've updated the answer with working examples.

Comment: Thanks, @U880D i already converted the playbook to match your instructions the only thing was missing was "https_proxy: "ProxyIP:Port" which was causing the issue so after some googling i came across https_proxy parameter and i set it on Playbook level and voila it worked. Thanks a ton