# 'unarchive' module in Ansible doesn't change owner and group of extracted files and folder

Tags: permissions, ansible, ownership

I wrote this to extract the files and folder on a remote server. 
It extracts them but doesn't change the owner and group of the extracted files.

```yaml
---                                                      
- name: Uncompressing the Tomcat source                  
  become: true                                           
  become_user: someuser                                      
  unarchive:                                             
    src: /rmtdir/apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz         
    dest: /rmtdir/                                          
    owner: someuser                                           
    group: somegroup                                           
    mode: 0770                                           
    remote_src: yes                                      
  register: _extract                                     
                                                         
- name:                                                  
  debug:                                                 
    var: _extract
```

Obviously, I want it to change the owner and group of the extracted files. 
How can I get it to do that?

Comment: I've been looking to do this too, but never found a proper way to do it... I used a `file` module with the `path`/`owner`/`group` and a `recurse`, last time I had to do it.

Comment: There is a workaround, like using role and add "become: true ;  become_user: someuser" then it will create extracted files with the user you want to be the owner. But i hoped unarchive can do it with using become. I came across file module but preferred not to use it as can change the ownership of wrong files and folder incase you dont know the name of extracted files and folder

Comment: Since I am not able to (re)produce an issue: Can you provide more details about the issue you are observing? Debugging details and console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up to [Ansible: Fails at `curl` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713751/266568) I've performed the following test

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    VERSION: "9.0.65"

  tasks:

  - name: Uncompressing the Tomcat source
    unarchive:
      src: https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v{{ VERSION }}/bin/apache-tomcat-{{ VERSION }}.tar.gz
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/tomcat"
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      group: "ansible_users"
      mode: 0770
      extra_opts: [--strip-components=1]
      remote_src: true
    environment:
      http_proxy: 'localhost:3128'
      https_proxy: 'localhost:3128'
    register: _extract

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: _extract
```

and found it working as expected.

> *It extracts them but doesn't change the owner and group of the extracted files.*

I wasn't able to produce the mentioned issue as owner and group of the extracted files became changed as they should.

Comment: Yes, very strange it didnt work so to overcome this i added a task which will create the folder and set proper owner and perms. later unarchive task will unarchive compressed file in newly created directory and all extracted files got parent folder permissions.